# Middleman Blog: Custom layout not loading

Tags: ruby, blogs, middleman

In Middleman, I am trying to set up a blog site, using custom layout for the blog. My problem is that the main layout is loading, but the blog layout for my articles is not. The article files are being served in with their plain body.

In `source/layouts/` I have two files: `layout.erb` and `article_layout.erb`.

My intent is to use `article_layout.erb` for my blog articles.

In config.rb I have the following:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.sources = "articles/{category}/{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  blog.layout = "article_layout"
end
```

I have also tried moving `article_layout.erb` to `source/articles/` as well as prepending the config.rb file like this: `blog.layout = "layouts/article_layout"`

Another failed approach is to comment out the above option and configure the layout by adding this line instead: `page "/articles/*", layout: "article_layout"`.

So far none of these approach show a difference. Since the default layout is not being rendered I would expect some sort of error message if the path to the layout cannot be found, but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to replicate your problem with my own Middleman blog setup.
The docs are unclear on this because there is a broken link in the layout section of Blogging.

You need to use the nested layout feature of Middleman and wrap your custom layout in:

```
<% wrap_layout :layout do %>

<% end %>
```

So your `article_layout.erb` would look something like this:

```
<% wrap_layout :layout do %>

 <div class="article-container"> 
   <article>
     <h2 class="article-title"><%= current_page.title %></h2>
     <%= yield %>
   </article>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

And keep your custom layout in the `source/layouts` folder.

Here are the docs for [Nested Layouts](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/layouts/#nested-layouts) for your reference.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I did see that. It was my intent to use a different layout altogether, but actually nested makes more sense. So I added the wrap.

Still no layouts are being loaded at all for my articles.

I have tried this as well:
    with_layout :article do
       page "/articles/*"
    end

Even when I comment out all specific layout options I would expect the blog to load the default template, which is loaded for all other pages, but that isn't happening either.

There are no other layout references in my files. Obviously I am overlooking something, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Could you post your `config.rb` as well as your `layout.erb` and `article_layout.erb`. If you have your project on Github you could just link to that if you feel comfortable.

Comment: Sure, it's a small personal project. I pushed up what I have now and made it public: https://github.com/rpbaptist/richardbaptist.nl

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing, but I just realized I didn't put my my blog pages in the .erb format. It's working just fine now.

Thank you so much for your patience and help.

Comment: If you are writing in **haml** you need to use `=` instead of `-`. So it would look like `= wrap_layout :layout do`. I guess this will also be the case with **slim**